# PushWoosh, ios, Cordova - won't install

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, pushwoosh

I'm trying to implement the PushWoosh plugin to my Cordova project. and i can't get the plugin to install so i can make a comile

Running Cordova 3.7.0 on Xcode 5.1.1
PushWoosh version 3.3.0

I create the project. Adds other plugins and build to ios. All OK. Cordova runs in Simulator.

Then i add pushwoosh plugin : cordova plugin add https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin.git

installs ok.

build with errors

```
error :  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/myuser/Desktop/Projekter/StaffCommunicator/platforms/ios/build/staffcommunicator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/staffcommunicator.build/Objects-normal/i386/PushNotification.d''. 
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “PushNotification.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fa1a1533730 
{NSFilePath=/Users/myuser/Desktop/Projekter/StaffCommunicator/platforms/ios/build/staffcommunicator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/staffcommunicator.build/Objects-normal/i386/PushNotification.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa1a1527490 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
NSFilePath = "/Users/myuser/Desktop/Projekter/StaffCommunicator/platforms/ios/build/staffcommunicator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/staffcommunicator.build/Objects-normal/i386/PushNotification.d";
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";}
```

It seemes like the the plugin is't copied to the plugin folder. I have tried to manually copy the plugin files to the catalog.

Now i get this error:
{name = (null), num = 7}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.

```
** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
CompileC build/staffcommunicator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/staffcommunicator.build/Objects-normal/i386/PushNotification.o staffcommunicator/Plugins/com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh/ios/PushNotification.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error: /Users/myuser/desktop/projekter/staffcommunicator/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 65
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

If i try to run it in xcode it still can't compile, i get this error...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PushNotificationManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in PushNotification.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does the plugin work???? os is it xcode...

Please help.

Kind regards
/Mikael

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin/issues/46

Comment: Hi again. i have upgraded til xcode 6 and all runs fine, but not the pushwoosh plugin. It installs fine by CLI but at build it says error: no such file or directory: '/Users/files/Desktop/StaffCommunicator/platforms/ios/staffcommunicator/Plugins/com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh/ios/PushNotification.m'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

** BUILD FAILED **
and i can se that there is no files in that catalog. any idears???

Comment: I solved it. Just drag the Pushwoosh.framework to the  project. and it will build...